# Pontuação de recompensa

Tags: debate, perguntas, recompensa

Ofereci recompensa para uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74631/requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-api-rest) a qual eu **realmente** preciso de uma resposta, ela possui um número relativo de visualizações mas tanto no SOpt quanto no SOen não obtive nenhuma resposta até agora.
Por isso optei pela recompensa, porém qual é a lógica de eu perder a minha pontuação oferecida se ninguém responder?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [*Quando eu ofereço uma recompensa, o que na verdade acontece?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2079)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O "preço" pago ao oferecer uma recompensa é uma forma de publicidade, você está pagando para que sua pergunta seja vista por mais pessoas.

E isso realmente funciona, pois sua pergunta fica por uma semana em uma [aba privilegiada de destaque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) das demais perguntas e também por que as pessoas têm interesse em um ganho de reputação mais elevado ao responder uma pergunta. Ou seja, você invariavelmente vai receber mais atenção na sua pergunta, graças ao sistema de recompensa.

Acontece que nem sempre as recompensas conseguem atrair respostas, isso geralmente acontece por dois motivos: ou por que a pergunta não tem resposta mesmo ou por que a pergunta tem problemas que impedem a compreensão por parte dos respondedores, seja por falta de clareza, por omissão de informações ou de qualquer outro motivo que impede a transmissão da real dúvida para os outros usuários do site.

Em todo caso, sua publicidade foi feita, e por isso o valor pago por ela não é reembolsável.

Para o seu caso em específico, acho que ainda é cedo para perder suas esperanças, sua pergunta está em destaque faz apenas um dia e já tem um comentário promissor de um usuário com boas chances de responder sua dúvida de forma satisfatória.

Comment: Perfeito! Realmente não tinha pensado nessa questão da publicidade/divulgação da pergunta, apesar de óbvio

Comment: Mas não entendo o que o SOpt ganha com isso (excluindo os pontos de reputação da "economia" do site). Só faz sentido se for pra evitar a "banalização" das recompensas, mas mesmo assim ainda é meio ilógico pra mim. Acho que "pagar" pela publicidade é meio forçado, porque o SOpt não recebe nada, só o usuário que perde a reputação conquistada (arduamente) sem ter nenhum benefício (uma vez que a pergunta não foi respondida, e ninguém em sã consciência vai oferecer recompensa pensando simplesmente em obter destaque na pergunta).

Comment: @gustavox A ideia é justamente evitar a banalização e/ou os abusos no sistema de recompensas. Se estiver claro para o usuário, desde o princípio, que a recompensa não é devolvida sob hipótese alguma, é de se esperar que ele se esforce o máximo possível para fazer uma pergunta de alta qualidade, para não desperdiçar os seus preciosos pontos. Acredito eu que por muitas vezes, quando o usuário despende esse esforço na melhoria da qualidade da pergunta, ele já acaba por receber respostas sem nem mesmo precisar de recompensa.

Comment: E o "preço" eu usei no sentido figurado, realmente, a SE não "recebe" os pontos da recompensa :)

Comment: Sim Math, eu entendi o ponto (tanto que coloquei pagar entre " ''), e é bem claro mesmo que não tem devolução. O sistema é justo neste ponto... Mas ainda não faz muito sentido pra mim. Quer dizer, faz sentido pra evitar a banalização, mas fico pensando se não haveria uma outra forma de resolver isso, porque não me parece certo perder os pontos se a pergunta não foi respondida. Não quero dizer solucionada, mas se não houve nenhuma resposta pra pergunta (com pontuação de pelo menos +1 p.ex.), não vejo sentido em perder os pontos, porque não terá havido vantagem nenhuma.

Comment: Tem mais um motivo pra perguntas não receberem qualquer tentativa de resposta. A pergunta pode ter sido feita de uma forma que, embora clara e respondível, não facilita a vida de quem vai se propor a respondê-la. É o caso de perguntas que citam massas de dados mas não fornecem a fonte, ou fornecem os dados na forma de uma imagem (que, naturalmente, não podem ser copiados!). Essa "preguiça" da parte do AP afugenta potenciais usuários aptos a responder simplesmente porque lhes dá trabalho. (continua)

Comment: Principalmente com usuários experientes, que já têm reputação suficiente pra não se interessarem por 50 ou 100 pontos apenas pelos pontos, esse afastamento é enorme. E isso tudo piora também quando o assunto não é trivial (uma tecnologia muito específica), dado que o público capacitado a responder já é muito menor.

Answer (score 6):

Daniela, as recompensas funcionam dessa maneira mesmo.

Por vezes, a pergunta é votada mais durante o período da recompensa, na maior parte das vezes por ser interessante, bem feita ou por procurar responder a algo raro.

De qualquer maneira, [é assim que o sistema funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). *"Todas as gratificações são pagas de antemão e não são reembolsáveis em caso algum"* pode lêr-se no link que coloquei.

É esperar que [alguns dos conhecedores de Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) te possam ajudar.

Comment: Sergio, mesmo estando escrito "Todas as gratificações são pagas de antemão e não são reembolsáveis em caso algum" acho que não custa perguntar.. Vamos supor que eu dei uma resposta em minha própria perguntar e segundo a comunidade através de votação aquela foi a melhor resposta para a mesma; após o termino do prazo máximo da reputação, o que ocorre com a mesma? ela é "perdida"?

Comment: @DorivalZanetto segundo as regras ([aqui no meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/224030)) recompensas são dadas automáticamente a respostas com pontuação superior a `+1`, a respostas tem de ser colocada depois de o periodo de recompensa começar e a resposta não ser da mesma conta de quem dá a recompensa.

Answer (score 1):

Os pontos são debitados para evitar os espertinhos que poderiam usar desse recurso para ganhar visibilidade, entre outros motivos já mencionados nas respostas acima.

Em outras palavras, se não houvesse um custo, todos ofereceriam recompensas por qualquer coisa irrelevante apenas para obter destaque.